# Is it possible to move, scale or rotate an object using ABSOLUTE value, to move it to the left for example?

Tags: objects, transforms, customization

I just start using Blender after 3 years of using 3DsMax and I find it very bad that I need to type negative values after hitting the <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> button to move, scale or rotate it to the left, you rotated it anticlockwise.

Example:

If I want to move a certain object to left in the $x$ axis I need to type $-5$ and to the right just $5$.

In 3DsMax if you positioned your mouse cursor at the left of the object your trying to move and type $5$ it will move $5$ to the left and if you type $-5$ it'll move $5$ to the right, cause in 3DsMax this is how you indicate the direction that you wanted it to move.

Is it possible to have this setting in Blender?

Comment: i am pretty sure there are different opinions what's better -> always change between mouse and keyboard or "just using keyboard" (which i think is a lot faster). I do not think that this is possible with standard Blender. Maybe there is an add-on for that. And for sure you could make this functionality possible via python.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You answered your own question I think.

Comment: +1, though definitely not something I want: I'm already annoyed when Blender decides where to forward keyboard events based on which region the mouse is in...